# Generate Azure Blob SAS token with APEX

Tags: azure, salesforce, blob, apex

I want to generate SAS Token, as per the Azure Doc following is the example for BLOB. I am still getting error. Can you please identify what is the mistake I am doing.

```
StringToSign = signedpermissions + "\n" +  
               signedstart + "\n" +  
               signedexpiry + "\n" +  
               canonicalizedresource + "\n" +  
               signedidentifier + "\n" +  
               signedIP + "\n" +  
               signedProtocol + "\n" +  
               signedversion + "\n" +  
               rscc + "\n" +  
               rscd + "\n" +  
               rsce + "\n" +  
               rscl + "\n" +  
               rsct
```

URL = https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/test.txt
canonicalizedresource = "/blob/myaccount/mycontainer/test.txt

I am getting following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:4b1d1c59-c01e-0052-0197-ffe09f000000
Time:2020-03-21T15:44:34.2757923Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Following is my code

```
public void getSasToken() {

    this.storageName = 'zaindevtesting';
    this.storageContainer = 'zaindevblob';
    this.storageKey = 'xxxxxxZFQ==';
    this.storageUrl ='https://zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net';

    Datetime sasExpiry = Datetime.now();
    sasExpiry.addMinutes(15);
    Datetime sasStart = Datetime.now();
    sasStart.addMinutes(-5);


    string signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
    String signedstart = sasStart.formatGMT('YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
    string signedexpiry = sasExpiry.formatGMT('YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
    string signedservice = 'b';
    String canonicalizedresource = '/blob/zaindevtesting/zaindevblob/test.txt';
    string signedidentifier = '';
    string signedIP = '';
    string signedProtocol = 'https';
    string signedversion = '2015-04-05';
    string rscc='';
    string rscd='';
    string rsce='';
    string rscl='';
    string rsct='';


    string stringToSign =signedpermissions + '\n' +  
               signedstart + '\n' +  
               signedexpiry + '\n' +  
               canonicalizedresource + '\n' +  
               signedidentifier + '\n' +  
               signedIP + '\n' +  
               signedProtocol + '\n' +  
               signedversion + '\n' +  
               rscc + '\n' +  
               rscd + '\n' +  
               rsce + '\n' +  
               rscl + '\n' +  
               rsct;

    string signedExpiryEncode = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signedexpiry, 'UTF-8'); 
    string signedStartEncode = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signedstart, 'UTF-8'); 
    String sasToken = '';
    Blob unicodeKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
    Blob data = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), unicodeKey);
    sasToken = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
    String sasTokenString= '?sv=' + signedversion + '&se=' + signedexpiry +'&st='+signedstart+'&sr='+signedservice+'&sp=' + signedpermissions + '&sig=' + sasToken;

    string sasURL = 'https://zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net/test.txt'+sasTokenString;
    System.debug('sasURL--->'+sasURL);
    System.debug(sasTokenString);
   // return sasToken;
}
```

This code generate following SAS Link

https://zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net/test.txt??sv=2017-11-09&st=2020-03-21T15%3A44%3A07Z&se=2020-03-21T15%3A44%3A07Z&sr=b&sp=rwdc&sig=eJVbGWI4rcyjggOYAE308ilXEA/zAsFYbuNi24IZhX4=

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
public void generateSASToken()
{
    string storageName = 'zaindevtesting';
    string storageContainer = 'zaindevblob';
    string storageKey = 'xxxx==';
    string storageUrl ='https://zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net';

    Datetime sasExpiry = Datetime.now();
    sasExpiry = sasExpiry.addMinutes(15);
    Datetime sasStart = Datetime.now();
    sasStart = sasStart.addMinutes(-5);


    string signedpermissions = 'r';
    String signedstart = sasStart.formatGMT('YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
    string signedexpiry = sasExpiry.formatGMT('YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
    string signedservice = 'b';
    String canonicalizedresource = '/blob/zaindevtesting/zaindevblob/test.txt';
    string signedidentifier = '';
    string signedIP = '';
    string signedProtocol = '';
    string signedversion = '2015-04-05';
    string rscc='';
    string rscd='';
    string rsce='';
    string rscl='';
    string rsct='';


    string stringToSign =signedpermissions + '\n' +  
        signedstart + '\n' +  
        signedexpiry + '\n' +  
        canonicalizedresource + '\n' +  
        signedidentifier + '\n' +  
        signedIP + '\n' +  
        signedProtocol + '\n' +  
        signedversion + '\n' +  
        rscc + '\n' +  
        rscd + '\n' +  
        rsce + '\n' +  
        rscl + '\n' +  
        rsct;
    System.debug('stringToSign--->'+stringToSign);
    string signedExpiryEncode = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signedexpiry, 'UTF-8'); 
    string signedStartEncode = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signedstart, 'UTF-8'); 
    String sasToken = '';
    Blob unicodeKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
    Blob data = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), unicodeKey);
    sasToken = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
    sasToken = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(sasToken, 'UTF-8');        
    String sasTokenString= '?sv=' + signedversion + '&se=' + signedexpiry +'&st='+signedstart+'&sr='+signedservice+'&sp=' + signedpermissions + '&sig=' + sasToken;

    string sasURL = 'https://zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net/zaindevblob/test.txt'+sasTokenString;
    System.debug('sasURL--->'+sasURL);
    System.debug(sasTokenString);
    // return sasToken;
}
```

I just tried it with **your storage account key** and I was able to download the blob.

Found the following issues with your code:

- Permissions has to be in specific order. You're using `string signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';` which is not the correct order. I just specified the `read` permission.
- Signed Protocol was specified in `stringToString` but was not included in the SAS URL. I omitted that from both places.
- SAS Token was not URL encoded.
- You generated SAS Token for `zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net/zaindevblob/test.txt` URL but forgot to include the blob container name in the final URL.

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav Mantri your solution work, I have one more question . Is there any way I can use Azure Javascript SDK without any syntax of Node Js? I want to use that SDK in lightning web component. But most of Microsoft Doc example has Node Js Syntax

Comment: Awesome! I am glad to hear that....It has been bothering you for quite some time now :). Regarding your question about using JS SDK, absolutely yes. The same SDK should work in browser as well.

Comment: For future solution/ issue finder, if you are using SAS token for uploading please use string signedpermissions = 'w'; // Write permission. There are also many as per Azure Doc. Whihc is Read=r, Write=w, Delete=d, Create=c and List=l

Comment: @ Gaurav Mantri Yes it was bothering for a while but I was able to Solve the issue with Shared Key for which I have also updated my previous post for future reference for other people. The only problem in that approach is that , I was not able to upload the large Blob from APEX code. So this is the reason I need to use Javascript upload and SAS token I will generate from APEX code.